# How to do hg revert --all with git?

Tags: git, mercurial

When using Mercurial it is possible to issue the following command:

`hg revert --all --rev <revision>`

The content of the working directory is set to the specified `<revision>` but you stay where you are in the tree (same parent, branch, etc).

How to do that in git?
It should behave like `git reset --hard <commit>` without moving the branch pointer.

TL;DR

`git config alias.revert-all 'read-tree -um HEAD'
git revert-all <commit>`

A comparison/test of all variants i found can be found here: http://git.io/vk9it

Comment: I hate to be That Guy, but I've just found that using `hg-git` is the easiest way to do anything in git.

Comment: Well its git, it does not have to be easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git read-tree -um @ $thatcommit
```

will do it.  That's "transition the index and worktree from the HEAD aka @ commit to $thatcommit, as for checkout (but without touching HEAD)".

When what you're doing isn't a good match for any of the convenience commands, the core commands have your back :-)

If you need to blow away uncommitted changes, `git reset --hard` possibly with some selection of `git clean` options to clear out completely untracked files first, git really hates stomping on uncommitted work without an explicit order.

Comment: Thats it! I found read-tree yesterday and was playing with it, but i only got it working with the index. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, another (slower) alternative:

`git diff --cached --full-index --binary <commit> | git apply --reverse --cached`

Only updates the index, to force it to the working directory to issue:

`git checkout-index -fa && git clean -dxf`

Answer (score -1):

> The content of the working directory is set to the specified  but you stay where you are in the tree (same parent, branch, etc).

In git your `HEAD` can point to a single commit. You cant have at the same time multiple HEADS (unless you use `git new-workdir` and then you have n copies of the repository)

The only thing that might be similar to this (but again its not exactly what you want) is to work with branches (same as in hg).

Once you have several branches you can have different HEAD per branch.

You don't have to use reset you can simply `branch` out at any given point:

`git checkout -b <branch_name> <SHA-1>`

and you will have a new branch pointing to the desired parent.

---

In git when you do a `git revert` you remain on the current branch but your parent is the commit prior to the current commit (the history is moving to the given point in the tree)

Comment: I understand the concept of branching, that's pretty far of... There is no way you can have multiple HEAD's in a single repository, and that's nothing I asked for. If my question lacks clarity please comment and i'll try to make it better... Btw. i did not downvote, but i can understand why someone would, no offence but you wrote things which are plain wrong (multiple HEAD's, `git revert` moving to a point). Just saying...